# ckEditor focus using angular framework

Tags: angularjs, focus, ckeditor

that cause a braindamage for me to use ckEditor with angular. 
When i try to focus ckEditor programmable after user click on answer button then ckEditor has no focus.

I`ve tried:

```
ck.focus()
```

and

```
var focusManager = new CKEDITOR.focusManager(ck);
focusManager.focus();
```

Nothing. After calling this methods ckEditor still has no focus on self.

angular directives (see the scope.$on function):

```
angular.module('ck', []).directive('ckEditor', function() {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
            var isReady = false;
            var data = [];
            var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0], {
                customConfig: 'lite_config.js',
                height: attr.height || 200
            });
            function setData() {
                if (!data.length) {
                    return;
                }

                var d = data.splice(0, 1);
                ck.setData(d[0] || '<span></span>', function() {
                    setData();
                    isReady = true;
                });
            }

            ck.on('instanceReady', function(e) {
                if (ngModel) {
                    setData();
                }
            });

            elm.bind('$destroy', function() {
                ck.destroy(false);
            });

            scope.$on('$focus', function() {
                ck.focus();
                var focusManager = new CKEDITOR.focusManager(ck);
                focusManager.focus();
            });

            var onChange = function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    var data = ck.getData();
                    if (data == '<span></span>') {
                        data = null;
                    }
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(data);
                });
            };

            if (ngModel) {
                ck.on('change', function() {
                    onChange();
                });
                ck.on('paste', function() {
                    onChange();
                });


                ngModel.$render = function(value) {
                    if (ngModel.$viewValue === undefined) {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(null);
                        ngModel.$viewValue = null;
                    }

                    data.push(ngModel.$viewValue);

                    if (isReady) {
                        isReady = false;
                        setData();
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    };
});
```

and thats my method in angular controller method:

```
    $scope.answer = function(parentComment) {
        resetForking();
        $scope.newComment = '';
        $scope.answering = true;
        parentCommentId = parentComment.comment.id;
        answerContentId = parentComment.comment.initiativeContentId;
        $scope.answerTo = parentComment.author.userName;
        $scope.$broadcast('$focus');
        utils.scrollDown();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
   CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',
{
    on :
    {
        instanceReady : function( ev )
        {
            CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.focus();
        }
    }
} );
```